# Pulling changed data from heroku

Tags: django, git, sqlite, heroku

I have deployed a Django app in Heroku. I want the updated SQLite file to be reflected in my local repository. Is there any way I can do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the command `heroku run bash` we can get access the remote heroku terminal. After accessing the file we can upload the file from the terminal using
https://transfer.sh/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`heroku ps:copy`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/exec#copying-files-from-a-dyno) to download your SQLite database files from Heroku and then commit it to your repository.

However, [SQLite is a poor fit for Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3) for a number of reasons. Consider instead using [Heroku Postgres](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql).

Comment: Yes, I know that SQLite is a poor fit for Heroku but I just want to try and learn how to use.

Comment: Is there any way that we can download the whole repo updated one to our local repo.